# Docker container ls not listing my pulled container?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, docker-for-windows, docker-image

I pull the tensorflow/serving in docker-for-windows Linux containers

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker pull tensorflow/serving
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from tensorflow/serving
Digest: sha256:f7e59a29cbc17a6b507751cddde37bccad4407c05ebf2c13b8e6ccb7d2e9affb
Status: Image is up to date for tensorflow/serving:latest
docker.io/tensorflow/serving:latest
```

After that for any following commands the container is not listing up

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I tried restarting docker as well, may I know how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`docker pull` is pulling the image you selected
You don't have a container yet.

`docker ps` and the other commands you used are referring to containers.

So to run the container use:

`docker run {options} image`

After that you be able to see the container using `docker ps`

Answer (score 3):

When you run `docker pull tensorflow/serving` the Docker image will get pulled, which can be listed using `docker images` command.

While `docker ps`, `docker container ls -a`, `docker container ls` will list running docker container. You need to run your Docker image using `docker run image-name` then the container will get listed using the mentioned commands.

For more info on Docker, please refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) official guide.